# Deluge: how to fetch Zoho CRM subform data

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

Hey I'm trying to get data from a Zoho CRM subform "PG_Info" to show up so I can merge it into a Zoho Writer template. When I try the code below it returns "null" for all entries. Any ideas?

```
r_Deal_Record = zoho.crm.getRecordById("Deals",Deal_Record_ID);
Subform = r_Deal_Record.get("PG_Info");
for each rec in Subform
{
field1 = rec.get("PG");
field2 = rec.get("SSN_PG");
field3 = rec.get("Ownership_Percent");
}
info field1;
info field2;
info field3;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

from your current code, the info's should be inside of the "for each" statement.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to get the subform records using related list data.
Please refer to your API Name page in your Zoho CRM organization.

Find `Deals` module and then change the selection from `Fields` to `Related Lists`. In there you will find the API Name of your subform.

For example, if the API Name of your subform is `PG_Info`, then you will be able to pull it using below code.

```
// r_Deal_Record = zoho.crm.getRecordById("Deals",Deal_Record_ID);
// Subform = r_Deal_Record.get("PG_Info");
subformPG = zoho.crm.getRelatedRecords("PG_Info", "Deals", Deal_Record_ID);
for each rec in Subform
{
    field1 = rec.get("PG");
    field2 = rec.get("SSN_PG");
    field3 = rec.get("Ownership_Percent");

    // info moved to inside for, as the subform allowing multiple records
    info field1;
    info field2;
    info field3;
}
```

[Zoho Help](https://www.zoho.com/deluge/help/crm/get-related-records.html)

Answer (score 0):

2 things to check:

#1. Double-check that the id number in Deal_Record_ID is correct and a record exists for it.  Do this through the Zoho CRM user interface instead of through deluge-code.

#2. Display the full Subform variable with `info Subform;`.  It may be 'null' (just like the record fields) but sometimes there is an error message or some data that is helpful to resolving the issue.